# Android: How can I apply a custom font to an active tab in TabLayout?

Tags: java, android, fonts, tabs, material-components-android

I am currently trying to change the font of an active tab using "com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout". I looked up several solutions like Typeface.createFromAssets() but it causes crashes. 
The reason why I don't use Typeface.BOLD is because it is a seperate font file or am I missing something?

Is there another solution to change the font of a tab at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Creat your own `TextView` Class model :

```
public class MyTextViewModel extends TextView {

    String font_path = "fonts/Your_font.ttf";


public MyTextViewModel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), font_path);
    this.setTypeface(tf);
}
public MyTextViewModel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), font_path);
    this.setTypeface(tf);
}
public MyTextViewModel(Context context) {
    super(context);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), font_path);
    this.setTypeface(tf);
}
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
}
```

and then create an xml file call it tab_text ,with your MyTextViewModel

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyTextViewModel
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@android:id/text"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
/>
```

and then apply it to your selected TabID

```
 MyTextViewModel tv = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_text,null)
 tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(tv);
```